# D3.js restore previous color on mouseout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js and try to highlight an element on mouseover. I have the problem that my rectangles change color on mouseover, but does not change back on mouseout. The elements have many different colors, so I can't hardcode what color the rectangle should get on mouseout.

Here is my code

Code where I make the rect

```
    nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .style("fill", color)
    .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover", seres.utilities.highlight)
    .on("mouseout", seres.utilities.downlight);
```

Color function called in above code

```
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3c3c3c" : d.children ? "#c2bcbc" : "#ffffff";
```

}

UtilityCode

```
var myMouseOver = function() {
    var rect = d3.select(this);
    rect.style("fill", "red");
}

var myMouseOut = function() {
    var rect = d3.select(this);
    rect.style("fill", 'DONTKNOWWHATTOPUTHERE');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the fill to equal a function. If you for example have the color value in your data object, it would be something like this:

```
var myMouseOut = function() {
    var rect = d3.select(this);
    rect.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I reckon I should have seen that solution myself

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call your `color` function again within your myMouseOut function. If you pass a function as your second argument in `rect.style()`, d3 will pass it `d` as an argument, so you can use:

```
var myMouseOut = function(d){
    d3.select(this)
      .style("fill",color);
};
```

I've created a fiddle showing how to do this [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kUneX/)

Comment: Thanks for the lightning-fast answer, however, Simenhg was the fastest, so I gave him the accepted checkmark.